# How i can edit fields "created" or "modified" and "modifed by" in sharepoint online c#

Tags: development, edit

i want to migrate files and folders from disk to office 365 , i did it well , now i want to have the possibility to chage fields : "modified" and "modifed by" to affect the real value not associated by sharepoint. i use windows forms c#. may be CSOM can do it but i don't find the solution yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following logic to update the items

```
ClientContext ctx = new ClientContext("http://site");
List list = ctx.Web.Lists.GetByTitle("ListTitle");
ListItemCollection items = list.GetItems(CamlQuery.CreateAllItemsQuery());
ctx.Load(items); // loading all the fields
ctx.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var item in items)
{
    item["Modified"] = "2015-07-03"; //Replace hardcoded value with the value in Excel/disk etc.
    //Similarly change other fields like created etc.
    item.Update(); //Apply the change
}
ctx.ExecuteQuery(); //Commit changes to the server
```

Comment: thanks for help , in my case i have to do this for libraries not a simple lists , i saw when i search for a solution that library is different to list ! how i can access to every file in a library and change the itm "modified" ?

Answer (score 0):

The fields `Created`, `Author`, `Modified` and `Editor` are readonly fields and can not be edited using the client API (CSOM).